# Yii2 calculate ratio for fields filled for signup form

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

Im new in Yii2, And Im try to get the ratio for fields filled by user in signup, what is best way to do that?

Example:
This is field in signup form: 
name, email, phone, address

And user fill name, and email only
The result for ratio must be: 50% filled

Note: We have relation fields too.

Comment: Try to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank for reply, I found answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it by using this widgets

https://github.com/aneeshikmat/formCompleteRatio

Good luck